# how i can stop repeating sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

[image]

i want to display one article with its 3 images but i can't it keeps displaying 3 times one article  with different images

`SELECT * FROM article, images WHERE article.idArticle = images.idArticle`

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: can you add ouput formatt you needed

Comment: Well, which image do you want to show? Also, you should switch to 'modern' explicit `join` syntax, rather than the antiquated implicit (comma separated) join syntax.

Comment: i want to display an article with 4 image without repeating the article 4 times

Comment: How to you display your article? One way could be to use `GROUP_CONCAT(images)` to get all your images in one row separated by `,`, then in your PHP you will have get each images and display it

Comment: but i have two tables in my sql

Comment: Can you show us the 2 tables structure please?

Comment: Where is the PHP code?

Comment: <?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=ar', 'root', '');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM article, images WHERE article.idArticle = images.idArticle");

$result->execute();
for ($i = 0;
$row = $result->fetch();
$i++){
?>
    <h1 style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['idArticle']; ?></h1>
    <hr>
    <img style="width: 300px" src="images/<?php if($row ['images'] !=null ) {echo $row ['images'];} ?>"><br>
   
    <h6><?php echo $row['textArticle']; ?><br></h6>
    <p><h5>Description</h5> <?php echo $row['dateArticle']; ?><br></p>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

Comment: You mention PHP, so handle the issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will list all your articles once and the images will be concatenated in the `IMG` column thanks to [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) (comma separated values).

```
SELECT article.idArticle, GROUP_CONCAT(images.images) AS IMG
FROM article
LEFT JOIN images ON article.idArticle = images.idArticle
GROUP BY article.idArticle
```

Comment: i don't have any colum by name of IMG

Comment: SQL query: Documentation


SELECT article.*, GROUP_CONCAT(images.images) AS IMG
FROM article
LEFT JOIN images ON article.idArticle = images.idArticle LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation
i get this error
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'ar.article.idArticle'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: `IMG` is an alias for the `GROUP_CONCAT` columns. I've edited and added a group by clause.

Comment: FWIW, this is not what I'd do.

Comment: it worked but in my php give me this error
 images in C:\wamp64\www\tedx\ArticleImage\index.php on line 27 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0004372896{main}( )...\index.php:0 ">

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you on the PHP field.